# How to use pdf.js library in a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, pdf.js

I'm making a Firefox add-on extension to `insert` a **pdf** document in the translated page of Google and I want to use `pdf.js`. Don't want to use embed or iframe tags to do it, I want to do my own **pdf** viewer.
I'm trying to use the `pdj.js` library in a Firefox add-on, but it not work. 
I have already tried to do it adding this in `manifest.json`.

```
    "content_scripts": [ 
    {
      "matches":["*://translate.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js","pdf.js"]
    }
   [enter image description here][1] ]
```

but when I do:

```
pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdf_url);
```

it not working, the script stop working.

I do try to add the script in the head of the page doing

```
var pdf_js = document.createElement('script');
pdf_js.src = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pdf_js);
```

and it does not work either. But when I use **pdfjsLib** from debug console in Firefox it works, but from the script that I use for the addon, `pdfjsLib.getDocument` function it not working.

I had a similar problem when I used jQuery, the library does not work in the script.

I tried watching the navigation console as suggested by **Jaromanda X** and I got this

ReferenceError:

> pdfjsLib is not defined

Comment: when you say that the script stops working is there an error/log that you are receiving and would be relevant to show here?

Comment: `but it not work` ... `it not working` ... `does not work either` ... yes, we get it doesn't work - check the browser console (Ctrl+Shift+J) - you'll see any errors your addon produces in there

Comment: ReferenceError: pdfjsLib is not defined

Comment: Where do I get pdf.js file - can you please help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was that the `manifest.json` in the `"content_scripts"`, in `"js"`, the order of scripts was is bad..

I had first and this not work because `script.js` (the addon script) is before that `pdf.js`

```
   "content_scripts": [ 
    {
      "matches":["*://translate.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["script.js","pdf.js"]
    }
```

the correct way is.

```
   "content_scripts": [ 
    {
      "matches":["*://translate.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["pdf.js","script.js"]
    }
```

in case of use Jquery, should are before of `script.js` too

```
 "js": ["jquery.min.js","pdf.js","script.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following line:

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```